# Header not showing in a Windows Phone 8 Dojo app

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

The Body of Index.html app generated by Worklight 6.2 contains the following HTML5 and it is not working properly on Windows Phone 8 emulator. I cannot see the Heading Bar and the comanylogo image.

```
<body style="display: none;">
    <div data-dojo-props="selected:false" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="view1">
        <div data-dojo-props="label:'Heading'" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">My View</div>
        <div>
        <img src="images/companylogo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error in the Visual Studio `Output` view? For example, something like `require is not defined`?
If so, make sure that in the generated native\www\index.html, the following line uses the correct IP address where the dojoLib is located, typically it is the same address as Worklight Development Server (Eclipse..):

```
<script data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="http://192.168.1.103:9988/dojoLib/test4/test/windowsphone8/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Once I've corrected the address used (I changed it in Visual Studio while the project was opened there), the app then rendered correctly. In the case of Windows Phone 8, theme is basically black background and white text...

In the RPE while in Worklight Studio, it uses some other theme.

See if that helps in any way.

Comment: I don't have any error in VS output. The scenario is, this is standalone app and it will not connect to Worklight server. All necessary files are self contained in the app and it will not connect to server to get the resources file (dojoLib).

Comment: I understand. Maybe this topic will help: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/wl_studio_tools/topics/t_remove_dojo_instrumentation_edit.html?lang=en

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes, I'm aware of getting the Dojo Library Resource feature cleared while building the app and the same app works fine on iOS (iPad). The Windows phone 8 app contains all the dojo, dojox resources under www/default folder. I guess some where the PATH to the resources is not getting set properly in worklight built app. Also the image file (companylogo.png) is not getting loaded.

Comment: The image issue is not related to Dojo; in my test the image loaded regardless of the dojoLib address. Not sure why it's not loading for you...

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and  Emulator 8.0.10322 WVGA 512MB and Worklight 6.2.0.01.20141002-2218.